# Read from io.PipeReader does not match write to io.PipeWriter

Tags: go

Running this program:

[on play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/dkbHTSeyn4_L)

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

func main() {
    r, w := io.Pipe()

    go func() {
        defer w.Close()
        in := 'a' // single quote
        fmt.Println("writing: ", in)
        fmt.Fprint(w, in)
    }()

    defer r.Close()

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    buf.ReadFrom(r)

    fmt.Print("read: ", buf.Bytes())

}
```

This outputs:

```
writing:  97
read: [57 55]
```

When I do `in := "a"` or `fmt.Fprint(w, string(r))`, it works as expected (`read: [97]`).

Is 97 equal to [57, 55] somehow?

Comment: `[57, 55]` is equal to `"97"`.

Comment: @tkausl so, how? I just cant understand, thanks for help!

Comment: 57 decimal == '9', 55 decimal == '7'. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html

Comment: If you meant to write the byte 'a', don't convert it to a string with fmt.Fprint. Call w.Write directly, for instance.

Comment: @Peter oh, It's "9" + "7", and fmt.Fprint did the conversion. thanks, so clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the two bytes `57` and `55` are the same as the two characters in the string `"97"`.  If you change your last line to use `String()` rather than `Bytes()`, you'll get the string:

```
fmt.Print("read: ", buf.String())
```

When you use `Bytes()`, you're getting the byte value of `"9"`, which is `57`, followed by that of `"7"`, which is `55`.

As pointed out by Peter in the comments, you might not be understanding what `fmt.Fprint` is doing—it's converting the rune `'a'` to the string `"97"` (this is the same as how `fmt.Println` is giving you "writing:  97").  If you don't want to do that conversion when you write to the pipe, then don't use `fmt.Printf`.  As Peter suggests, `w.Write` is a good option.  For example, `w.Write([]byte{byte(in)})` does what you seem to want, and allows the final line to work the way you want unchanged.  Another option would be `fmt.Fprintf(w, "%c", in)`.